# Getting Least Common Equal Sum and Combination of Two Sets of Numbers

Tags: math, combinatorics

I'm currently creating a program in C# that would look for the lowest possible equal sum of two sets of numbers, in which you may repeat the numbers as many times as you want.

For example, I have these two sets `{ 10, 13, 18 }` and `{ 12, 16, 22 }`. The lowest possible sum that I can get is **28**: `(10 + 18)` and `(12 + 16)`.

Another example is `{5, 7, 9}` and `{1, 2, 3}`. Lowest possible sum is **5**: `(5)` and `(1+1+1+1+1)` or `(1+2+2)` or `(2+3)` and so on.

Any suggestions on where I can start? I'll actually be using 6 numbers per set and the numbers are in the hundreds / thousands mark.

Comment: Hint: If you can find a way to generate all possible sums for a given set in increasing order, you can use a list merge to find the smallest sum shared by two sets.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to generate possible sums with minimal code effort. Let me see what I can come up then.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure either, but I think producing each sorted list of sums will involve recursively merging all the possible lists of sums you can get by adding each of the different elements to the sum so far.

Comment: Thanks, somehow i got an idea based on what you just said now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain two sets, initialized from your input sets, and ordered by increasing numbers (e.g. using a tree-based set structure). Now compare the first (i.e. minimal) elements from the two sets. The smaller one you remove from its set, add all elements from the corresponding input set to that value, and insert the results. When both sets have the same minimal element, then you are done and that element is your least common equal sum.

Comment: Thanks, let me do a bit of researching on how to do your suggestion.

Comment: I was able to do some iterations to get the sums. List<T>.Intersect() made it fast to track if I have a common sum. Thanks for this tip.