# Find all possible sub arrays from array Z that sum up to X

Tags: arrays, math, sum, combinations

I have a relatively complex issue, I need an algorithm to find all possible sub arrays from an array that sum up to X, so for the given array:

```
{2,8,12,45,32,7,6,5}
```

lets say we need subarrays that sum to 20, some would be:

```
{8,12} {2,7,6,5} {12,6,2}
```

however there will be combinations like:

```
{7,7,6} {5,5,5,5} {8,8,2,2}
```

I will need all possible sums.

I have done a solution doing brute force checking of all possibilities however it takes way too long (in some cases in excess of 30 minutes) to complete, so I do need a smarter solution that I've been bumping my head over for a couple of days now.

Comment: [It is a complicated problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Comment: Although a subset like {7,7,6} implies that you're allowed to pull the same element from the set more than once?

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: try cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can you show your code for how you currently brute force the solution.  There may be some optimizations that can be used to reduce the number of combinations.  Also, are there any other constraints that need to be applied?  When you say that "I will need all possible sums."  Do you need just the sums that add up to your target value, or do you need all possible sums from all possible combinations?

Comment: Is this in any way related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/12959936/1468366? I find it surprising that two questions about sums generated from sets with repeating elements are asked in such a short time.

Comment: that is surprising, I think it is related but not the same :> PS thanks for your answer I added another comment to it.

Comment: @mikurski Yes you allow elements more then once

Comment: @RBarryYoung its just a loop of all possibilities starting from 0,0,0,0,0,0 done by finding the sum needed first with the maximum number of elements used from the original set, so that means I use the smallest element in the set to determine the maximum.

Comment: @MvG not sure if I flagged you before (new contributor to stackoverflow) :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to indicate that answers which repeat numbers are acceptable, and you don't want to generate all possible ways the summands can be ordered. I'll base my answer on that.

I'd implement this in C++. As data structure, I'd probably use something like this:

```cpp
struct partial_sum {
  int min_last_summand;
  std::vector< std::pair<partial_sum*, int> > prefixes;
};

std::map<int, partial_sum*> m;
```

The central piece here is the map `m`. It maps the value of a sum to some information about how to obtain it. You'd initialize it with `0` mapped to `NULL`. The `prefixes` member would store data about all possible ways to obtain a given sum. The first part of each pair gives a pointer to information about all summands except the last, while the second part gives that last member. This gives you a form of directed acyclic graph, as sums can be prefixes of many sums, and sums can have many different prefixes, but the value of every prefix sum is smaller than that of the current sum.

The central iteration step would remove the minimal elkement from `m`, and generate all possible ways you can add an element from your input set to the value you just removed. So you'd check the map whether you need to insert a new entry for the new sum. And for existing and new entries alike, you create a new item in the `prefixes` list, with the pointer you just removed from the map as first part, and the last summand you added as the second.

I'd only generate sums in ascending (or rather non-descending) order of summands, to avoid generating all permutations. To make things easier, I'd maintain this `min_last_summand` information. It should always contain the minimum of all the second elements from the pairs in the `prefixes` list. When generating new sums, you can skip those where the last summand would be less than the minimal last summand of the prefix, as that would imply a summand being smaller than its predecessor. You could also avoid generating sums where the total value is greater than your target sum.

When printing the results, you'll have to recurse over the part of the DAG reachable from your target sum, and list all paths from there to the root `NULL`. So in each recursion step, you'd have a pointer to the current partial sum. If that pointer is `NULL`, you emit a sum consisting of zero summands. Otherwise, you iterate over all `prefixes`. For each prefix, you recurse to generate all possible ways to write that prefix, but only if the `min_last_summand` of the first element is no greater than the current last summand, and also only if the second element is no greater than the summand that will follow it. Which means that you'll have to pass that following summand as an argument to your recursive calls. Taken together, this avoids generating sums with descending steps in them.

The approach above assumes that your program will terminate after one run, so you don't have to worry about freeing memory. If you do, you'll probably have to store pointers to all the objects you created, so you can free them all.

Comment: This is a great solution thanks, one issue tho, this solves the issue if your set of possible numbers, the original set, is smaller then the set of numbers needed to create the sum.

So what I mean by that is, imagine we have only {7,6} as the original set the sum needed is 59, so you need something like this to be the result:
{7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,6}
This solution wouldn't get to that set right? Or am I just implementing it poorly :>

Comment: The approach outlined above *should* give you solutions with repeated elements, too. That's the reason I often wrote “non-decreasing” instead of “increasing”. If the last summand of a prefix is *a*, and *b* is the summand that follows it in the next larger sequence, then you should check that `a <= b`. One mistake of writing `a < b` there will suppress repeated elements. See whether you can fix that yourself, and if not, perhaps post a new question, giving your code and asking for a way to include duplicates.

Comment: actually just modified it so that I add numbers on every cycle until I reach or exceed the needed sum and works perfectly!! Thanks so very much :>